# I'm trying to attach a loop to my else statement

Tags: python, loops

It's running the first half how I'd like it to but it's ignoring my else statement. I'm trying to attach a loop to my else statement. Any advice would be great! I'll attach my code below:

```
num =input("Enter a number:")
print(num)
inc = input("Enter an increment:")
print(inc)

if inc <= str(0):
     print("Enter an increment greater than 0.") #works up until else--get loop to work!

else:
    for ctr in range(1, inc + 1, 1):
        print(ctr)
```

Comment: `str(0)` turns the number 0 into the string 0. So in your if statement, you are comparing strings, which is done by "lexicographic" order and probably not at all what you want. Instead, turn inc (and num) into numbers using `int` or `float`

Comment: are you trying to enter a number higher than 0 in the input?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to make it state "Enter an increment greater than 0." for any negative integers. But make it loop through even numbers for all other responses.

Answer (score 0):

you need to type cast properly. Also, you are not using `num` anywhere in the code

```
num =int(input("Enter a number:")) #int type cast
print(num)
inc = int(input("Enter an increment:")) #int type cast
print(inc)

if inc <= 0: # remove str type cast
     print("Enter an increment greater than 0.")

else:
    for ctr in range(1, inc + 1): # no need of step argument of 1. It is 1 by default
        print(ctr)
```

Comment: Should I add num in under my if statement as well? or does it go in my else statement? Is the lack of num why it won't loop? Thank you for responding!!

Comment: Loop is executing just fine for me. If I give 2 and any number greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

The input() function returns a string; you'll need to cast it to an integer. Try this:

```
if inc <= 0:
     print("Enter an increment greater than 0.")
else:
    for ctr in range(1, inc + 1):
        print(ctr)
```

Comment: Thank you! I switched them to integers and cleaned up my loop but the loop still is not running.

Comment: Strange; I wrote the script and tested it myself. Are you getting an exception, or are you entering some invalid number?

Comment: I'm entering 11 and 2 after I test the inc with -1. Would those qualify as invalid?